# Sql server query clarification

Tags: sql-server

I have table like below,

```
Txn_Id    Txn_Type
___________________
1         101
1         102
1         103
1         104
2         101
2         102
2         104
3         101
3         104
```

I want rows which has only txn_type 101 and 104. For eg., I should get only Txn_Id "3" for above data.

I tried like below and getting result. Is it possible to have single query to achive this.

```
Select txn_id from Txn where txn_id in (Select txn_id from Txn where txn_id = 101) and txn_id =104.
```

Comment: -Pls see below comment and clarify if i am right?

Answer (score 3):

```
Select txn_id from Txn where txn_type in (101,104)
```

option 2

```
    Select txn_id from Txn where (txn_type = 101 OR txn_type=104)
```

To get only "3"

```
Select distinct txn_id from Txn t1 where (txn_type = 101 OR txn_type=104)
and not exists(
select 1 from Txn t2 where t2.txn_type IN (102,103) and t2.txn_id = t1.txn_id
)
```

Comment: I feel OP wants those rows which has only txn_type 101 and 104. The resultant txn_id should not contain any other txn_id's in it. We you run your query you get all the txn_id's (i.e 1,2,3).But OP wants only txn_id 3.

Comment: Yes I want ONLY txn_id 3.

Answer (score 0):

Hi As per your above comments you only need the txn_id =3(max)

Please Find the code below.

```
DECLARE @Table1  TABLE 
    (txn_id int, Txn_Type int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
     (txn_id , Txn_Type )
VALUES
    (1, 101),
    (1, 102),
    (1, 103),
    (1, 104),
    (2, 101),
    (2, 102),
    (2, 104),
    (3, 101),
    (3, 104)
  ;


Select max(txn_id ),Txn_Type 
  from @Table1 where item in (101,104)
  group by Txn_Type
```

Comment: Coincidently this solution may work, but what if  txn_id 2 has only Txn_Types 101,104. In that case your query does not return the required output....

Comment: Just curious as to how you can do it by joining the table twice,but  I do understand that OP wants it to be in single query....

Answer (score 0):

As balaji pointed out, @Ayush solution is not flexible, since will return incorrect results if you, for example, add another pair of records in the table (4,101) and (4,104). IMO, you have to join table to itself for some filtering, something like this:

```
DECLARE @Table1  TABLE 
    (txn_id int, Txn_Type int);

INSERT INTO @Table1
     (txn_id , Txn_Type )
VALUES
    (1, 101),
    (1, 102),
    (1, 103),
    (1, 104),
    (2, 101),
    (2, 102),
    (2, 104),
    (3, 101),
    (3, 104),
    (4, 101),
    (4, 104);

select t1.*
from @Table1 t1
inner join (select txn_id, count(*) as total
        from @Table1 
        group by Txn_id
        having count(*) < 3
        ) t2 on t2.txn_id = t1.txn_id
where t1.Txn_Type in (101,104)
```